# angular2, angular2-highcharts. Remove a chart from the page

Tags: highcharts, angular

I have parent component (A) with two child components (B) & (C). B contains an angular2-tree which is populated on page load. C is where angular2-highcharts and information will be rendered when a node on the tree is clicked.

When navigating between nodes, sometimes I will show charts and others I wont. Currently, when I don't pass data to the chart options, assuming I've already shown a chart, then the chart continues to render.

How do I destroy the chart when I don't want it to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didnt think of a way to destroy the chart, but have added *ngIf to the html tag for the chart. This will hide the chart when the options are set to null.